# Using NIntegrate inside NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I need to use `NIntegrate` inside `NDSolve`, for example:

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == x + NIntegrate[r, {r, 1, y[x]}], y[2] == 0.5}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Why not a. evaluate the integral explicitly; or b. differentiate again so that you have a true ODE instead of an integro-differential equation?

Answer (score 8):

This may be a perverse way of solving the problem as stated, but as general technique it may be useful.  Define an auxiliary function that is only evaluated for numeric arguments, e.g.

```
f[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[r, {r, 1, y}]

m = NDSolve[{y'[x] == x + f[y[x]], y[2] == 0.5}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: How should I define coefficients of ODE including `NIntegrate` if ODE is intended for `ParametricNDSolveValue`? So far I tried someting like `A1N[k_?IntegerQ, bv_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := bva2D1N[k, bv, p]/bva2N[k, bv, p];` where `p` is free parameter and `bv` is substituted by `bv[z]` in final form of ODE for function `phi[z]`. All functions with names ended by `N` are some call to `NIntegrate`.
`

Comment: I suggest you ask this as a question where it will be seen by more people.