# How to modify NDSolve`StateData without crashing the kernel?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, undocumented, compatibility

Probably a hard question, but it's better to cry out loud.

[Reminded by Chris K](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51136457#51136457), I noticed my  [`fix`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129193/1871) function has been broken since *v11.3*. After some checking, I found `` NDSolve`StateData[…] ``, which is not an atom in *v9* and becomes an atom now, can no longer be modified with pattern matching.

To keep `fix` up to date, I tried the solution in this [excellent post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96225/1871) about modifying data inside atom, sadly the modified `` NDSolve`StateData `` crashes the kernel in the `` NDSolve`ProcessSolutions `` stage **even in *v9*** and I can't figure out a workaround.

The following is a simplified example attempting to modify the difference order to `2`. The last line crashes the kernel of course so please save your work before testing.

```
tmax = 10; lb = 0; rb = 5;
system = With[{u = u[t, x]}, {D[u, t] == D[u, x, x], u == 0 /. t -> 0, 
                              u == Sin[t] /. x -> lb, u == 0 /. x -> rb}];

{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[system, u, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, lb, rb}];

teststate = 
  state /. a_NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivativeFunction :> 
    RuleCondition@
     NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[a@"DerivativeOrder", a@"Coordinates", 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, PeriodicInterpolation -> a@"PeriodicInterpolation"];

Head[#]["DifferenceOrder"] & /@ 
 teststate["NumericalFunction"]["FunctionExpression"][[2, 1]]
(* Should give {{2}} if the replacement succeeds. *)

(*Failed attempt: *)
ml = LinkCreate[LinkMode -> Loopback];
LinkWrite[ml, With[{e = state}, Hold[e]]];
holdstate = LinkRead[ml];

newstate = holdstate /. 
   a_NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivativeFunction :> 
    RuleCondition@
     NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[a@"DerivativeOrder", a@"Coordinates", 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, PeriodicInterpolation -> a@"PeriodicInterpolation"] // 
  ReleaseHold

NDSolve`Iterate[newstate, tmax]

(*Warning: the following line crashes the kernel.*)
u /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions@newstate
```

Any way to avoid the crashing and fix my `fix` function?

---

A bit of spelunking shows this seems to be (at least partly) related to `` Internal`Bag ``. A minimal example:

```
bag = Internal`Bag[]
ml = LinkCreate[LinkMode -> Loopback];
LinkWrite[ml, With[{e = bag}, Hold[e]]]
holdbag = LinkRead[ml]
LinkClose[ml]
ReleaseHold[holdbag] === bag
(* False *)
```

Comment: I think the relation to `Bag` is only really in the fact that both are mutable object stored at the C++ level