# NDSolve matrix of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

If I have a system of differential equations that I can write in matrix form

$$\frac{\text{d}\mathbf{X}(t)}{\text{d}t} = \mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{X}(t),$$

with known initial conditions ($\mathbf{X}(0)=\mathbf{X}_0)$, how can I simulate the evolution of the components of $\mathbf{X}(t)$ using `NDSolve`?

Comment: Note that the particular ODE you presented can be easily solved with `MatrixExp[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---**UPDATE: A simpler approach**---

As per the comment by @J. M.'s discontentment, we can use the following code. Here, random numbers are used for `A` and `X0` for illustration.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
tEnd = 10;
X0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 4];
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}];
sol = x[t] /. 
   NDSolve[{x'[t] == A.x[t], x[0] == X0}, x, {t, 0, tEnd}];
Plot[sol, {t, 0, tEnd}]
```

---**ORIGINAL ANSWER: Unnecessarily complicated approach for most (if not all) cases**---

In the code below, the 'user' specifies the following:

- `L`: The size of $\mathbf{X}$, i.e. the number of simultaneous equations
- `tEnd`: The simulation duration
- `X0`: The initial conditions $\mathbf{X}_0$ (here a random vector is used for illustration)
- `A`: The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ (here a random matrix is used for illustration)

First, the components of $\mathbf{X}(t)$ are represented by dummy `variables` using `Unique`. Then the function `X[t]` is created from these. Then the `system` of equations and the initial condition `constraints` are stated. Then `NDSolve` is used to solve the system of equations subject to the constraints.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
L = 4;
tEnd = 10;
X0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, L];
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {L, L}];
variables = Table[Unique["x"], {L}];
X[t_] = #[t] & /@ variables;
system = X'[t] == A.X[t];
constraints = X[0] == X0;
sol = X[t] /. 
   NDSolve[{system, constraints}, variables, {t, 0, tEnd}];
Plot[sol, {t, 0, tEnd}]
```

[image: Figure generated from the code]

Comment: It's not necessary to define `variables`. `NDSolve` can handle implicit matrix. A recent example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230683/1871

Comment: In addition to @xzczd's example, see [the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html#37159131) as well.

Comment: Oh yeah. Woops. Thanks!