# Spalart-Allmaras turbulence model

Tags: modeling, finite-difference-method, fluid-dynamics

In [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/217201/testing-turbulence-models) Alex gives an implementation of the Spalart-Allmaras turbulence model [[1](https://turbmodels.larc.nasa.gov/Papers/RechAerosp_1994_SpalartAllmaras.pdf), [2](https://turbmodels.larc.nasa.gov/spalart.html#sa)]. The example produces reasonable results, as far as I can tell. However, the implementation Alex uses deviates from the paper and standard references in several ways. I would like to write a SA turbulence model that is closer to the original definition.

So we have:

```
saEQN = D[nut[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y]*D[nut[t, x, y], x] == 
   cb1*(1 - ft2)*STilda*
     nut[t, x, 
      y] - (cw1 fw - (cb1/\[Kappa]^2)* ft2)*(nut[t, x, y]/d)^2 + (1/
        sigma (D[(nu + nut[t, x, y]) D[nut[t, x, y], x], x] + 
         D[(nu + nut[t, x, y]) D[nut[t, x, y], y], y]) + 
      cb2/sigma*(D[nut[t, x, y], x]^2 + D[nut[t, x, y], y]^2));
```

Couple this to the fluid equation:

```
mut = rho*nut[t, x, y]*fv1;
fluidEQN = 
  D[u[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y]*D[u[t, x, y], x] + px == 
   D[(mu + mut) D[u[t, x, y], y], y] + D[u[t, x, y], x, x];
```

Here are the model definitions:

```
sigma = 2/3; kappa = .41; cb1 = 0.1355; cb2 = 0.622; eps = 10^-6; d = Sqrt[y^2 + eps^2]; cw1 = cb1/kappa^2 + (1 + cb2)/sigma;
cw2 = 0.3; cw3 = 2; cv1 = 7.1; ct1 = 1; ct2 = 2; ct3 = 1.2; ct4 = 0.5;
mu = 1.711*10^-5;
rho = 1;
nu = mu/rho;

omega = 1/2 Sqrt[(D[u[t, x, y], y] - D[u[t, x, y], x])^2];
chi = nut[t, x, y]/nu;
fv1 = chi^3/(chi^3 + cv1^3);
fv2 = 1 - chi/(1 + chi*fv1);
Omega = Sqrt[2*omega*omega];
STilda = Omega + nut[t, x, y]/(kappa^2*d^2)*fv2;
g = r + cw2 (r^6 - r);
r = Min[nut[t, x, y]/(STilda*kappa^2*d^2), 10];
fw = g*((1 + cw3^6)/(g^6 + cw3^6))^(1/6);
ft2 = ct3 Exp[-ct4*chi^2];
```

Set up the coupled equations:

```
eq = {saEQN, fluidEQN};
```

Set up the boundary conditions. These are updated boundary conditions Alex provided to avoid a message of NDSolve.

```
bcUpdate = {
   nut[t, x, 0] == 0, u[t, x, 0] == 0,
   nut[t, x, L] == 0.1, u[t, x, L] == 1,
   nut[t, 0, y] == 0.1 y/L, u[t, 0, y] == y/L,
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][nut][t, L, y] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, L, y] == 0};
```

A side question: My understanding is that for the SA turbulence model typically nut is set to 0 at the boundaries, why is that not the case here?

Initial conditions:

```
ic = {nut[0, x, y] == 0.1 y/L, u[0, x, y] == y/L};
```

Geometry, time and pressure:

```
L = 10^4;
t0 = 15;
px = 0;
```

Solve the equations:

```
Monitor[{nutTGP, uTGP} = 
   NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bcUpdate}, {nut, u}, {t, 0, t0}, {x, 0, 
     L}, {y, 0, L},
    EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])
    ];, monitor]
```

NDSolve give a *warning* message:

General::munfl: Exp[-87139.3] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

I think we can ignore it. When I look at the result

```
Plot3D[nutTGP[t0, x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I was expecting something more like the result from Alex's plot:

[image]

I can not see what I am doing wrong. Perhaps I need to scale the equations differently? Does anyone spot where my implementation goes south?

---

Complete code for my implementation:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(* SA eqn *)
saEQN = D[nut[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y]*D[nut[t, x, y], x] == 
   cb1*(1 - ft2)*STilda*
     nut[t, x, 
      y] - (cw1 fw - (cb1/\[Kappa]^2)* ft2)*(nut[t, x, y]/d)^2 + (1/
        sigma (D[(nu + nut[t, x, y]) D[nut[t, x, y], x], x] + 
         D[(nu + nut[t, x, y]) D[nut[t, x, y], y], y]) + 
      cb2/sigma*(D[nut[t, x, y], x]^2 + D[nut[t, x, y], y]^2));
(* fluid eqns *)
mut = rho*nut[t, x, y]*fv1;
fluidEQN = 
  D[u[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y]*D[u[t, x, y], x] + px == 
   D[(mu + mut) D[u[t, x, y], y], y] + D[u[t, x, y], x, x];

(* model parameters *)
sigma = 2/3; kappa = .41; cb1 = 0.1355; cb2 = 0.622; eps = 10^-6; d = 
 Sqrt[y^2 + eps^2]; cw1 = cb1/kappa^2 + (1 + cb2)/sigma;
cw2 = 0.3; cw3 = 2; cv1 = 7.1; ct1 = 1; ct2 = 2; ct3 = 1.2; ct4 = \
0.5;
mu = 1.711*10^-5;
rho = 1;
nu = mu/rho;
omega = 1/2 Sqrt[(D[u[t, x, y], y] - D[u[t, x, y], x])^2];
chi = nut[t, x, y]/nu;
fv1 = chi^3/(chi^3 + cv1^3);
fv2 = 1 - chi/(1 + chi*fv1);
Omega = Sqrt[2*omega*omega];
STilda = Omega + nut[t, x, y]/(kappa^2*d^2)*fv2;
g = r + cw2 (r^6 - r);
r = Min[nut[t, x, y]/(STilda*kappa^2*d^2), 10];
fw = g*((1 + cw3^6)/(g^6 + cw3^6))^(1/6);
ft2 = ct3 Exp[-ct4*chi^2];

(* eqns, bcs, ics *)
eq = {saEQN, fluidEQN};
bcUpdate = {
   nut[t, x, 0] == 0, u[t, x, 0] == 0,
   nut[t, x, L] == 0.1, u[t, x, L] == 1,
   nut[t, 0, y] == 0.1 y/L, u[t, 0, y] == y/L,
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][nut][t, L, y] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, L, y] == 0};
ic = {nut[0, x, y] == 0.1 y/L, u[0, x, y] == y/L};
(* geometry, time, pressure *)
L = 10^4;
t0 = 15;
px = 0;

(* solving *)
Monitor[{nutTGP, uTGP} = 
   NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bcUpdate}, {nut, u}, {t, 0, t0}, {x, 0, 
     L}, {y, 0, L},
    EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])
    ];, monitor]

(* plot *)
Plot3D[nutTGP[t0, x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Complete code for my Alex' implementation:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
L = 10^4;
t0 = 15;
px = 0;
sigma = 2/3; kappa = .41; cb1 = .1355; cb2 = .622; eps = 10^-6; d = 
 Sqrt[y^2 + eps^2]; cw1 = 
 cb1/kappa^2 + (1 + cb2)/
   sigma; cw2 = .3; cw3 = 2; cv1 = 7.1; ct1 = 1; ct2 = 2; ct3 = 1.2; \
ct4 = .5;
mu = 1.711 10^-5;
omega = Sqrt[(D[u[t, x, y], y] - D[u[t, x, y], x])^2];
chi = nu[t, x, y]/mu;
S = omega + (1 - chi/(1 + chi^4/(cv1^3 + chi^3))) nu[t, x, 
      y]/(kappa d)^2;
r = nu[t, x, y]/S/(kappa d)^2;
fw = (r + 
     cw2 (r^6 - r)) ((1 + cw3^6/(cw3^6 + (r + cw2 (r^6 - r))^6)))^(1/
      6);
ft2 = ct3 Exp[-ct4 chi^2];
nut = nu[t, x, y] chi^3/(cv1^3 + chi^3);
eq = {mu*(D[nu[t, x, y], t] + 
       u[t, x, y] D[nu[t, x, y], x]) == (cb1 (1 - ft2) S nu[t, x, 
        y] - (cw1 fw - 
         cb1/kappa^2 ft2) (nu[t, x, y]/d)^2 + (1/
          sigma (D[(nut + mu) D[nu[t, x, y], x], x] + 
           D[(nut + mu) D[nu[t, x, y], y], y]) + 
        cb2/sigma  (D[nu[t, x, y], x]^2 + D[nu[t, x, y], y]^2))), 
   D[u[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y] D[u[t, x, y], x] + px == 
    D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[(nut/mu + 1) D[u[t, x, y], y], y]};
bcUpdate = {nu[t, x, 0] == 0, u[t, x, 0] == 0, u[t, x, L] == 1, 
   nu[t, x, L] == 0.1, nu[t, 0, y] == 0.1 y/L, u[t, 0, y] == y/L, 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][nu][t, L, y] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, L, y] == 0};
ic = {nu[0, x, y] == 0.1 y/L, u[0, x, y] == y/L};
Monitor[{nuTPG1, UTPG1} = 
   NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bcUpdate}, {nu, u}, {t, 0, t0}, {x, 0, 
     L}, {y, 0, L}
    , EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = 
       Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];, monitor]
Plot3D[nuTPG1[t0, x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Comment: It is a good approach (+1), but my post was about very special case of turbulent boundary layer.

Comment: @Alex, yes I start to understand that now. I am thinking about a more general approach for turbulence modeling. I'll think more about this but your post has already been helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are several remarks concerning Spalart-Allmaras turbulence model (SA) for aerodynamic applications, published in [AIAA Paper 92 - 0439, 1992](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236888804_A_One-Equation_Turbulence_Model_for_Aerodynamic_Flows). First, to compare SA with our [turbulence model](https://www.witpress.com/Secure/elibrary/papers/AIR96/AIR96028FU.pdf) we need to rescale SA so that the space scale $l$ and velocity scale $u_0$ connect with dynamic viscosity $\mu$ as follows $l u_0=\mu /\rho$. Due to this rescaling we have equations for the flow velocity and turbulent viscosity in the form

```
saEQN = mu (D[nut[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y]*D[nut[t, x, y], x]) == 
   cb1*(1 - ft2)*STilda*
     nut[t, x, 
      y] - (cw1 fw - (cb1/\[Kappa]^2)*ft2)*(nut[t, x, y]/d)^2 + (1/
        sigma (D[(mu + mut) D[nut[t, x, y], x], x] + 
         D[(mu + mut) D[nut[t, x, y], y], y]) + 
      cb2/sigma*(D[nut[t, x, y], x]^2 + D[nut[t, x, y], y]^2));


    fluidEQN = 
      D[u[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y]*D[u[t, x, y], x] + px == 
       D[(1 + mut/mu) D[u[t, x, y], y], y] + D[u[t, x, y], x, x];
```

where `mut = rho*nut[t, x, y]*fv1;`. Second, in the wall region we use `omega = Sqrt[(D[u[t, x, y], y] - D[u[t, x, y], x])^2];` and `STilda = omega + nut[t, x, y]/(kappa^2*d^2)*fv2;`. Third, we use the homogenous Neuman bc at `x==L` to avoid message from `NDSolve`. Finally, the code is given by

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

sigma = 2/3; kappa = .41; cb1 = 0.1355; cb2 = 0.622; eps = 10^-6; d = 
 Sqrt[y^2 + eps^2]; cw1 = cb1/kappa^2 + (1 + cb2)/sigma;
cw2 = 0.3; cw3 = 2; cv1 = 7.1; ct1 = 1; ct2 = 2; ct3 = 1.2; ct4 = \
0.5;
mu = 1.711*10^-5;
rho = 1;
nu = mu/rho;

omega = Sqrt[(D[u[t, x, y], y] - D[u[t, x, y], x])^2];
chi = nut[t, x, y]/nu;
fv1 = chi^3/(chi^3 + cv1^3);
fv2 = 1 - chi/(1 + chi*fv1);
STilda = omega + nut[t, x, y]/(kappa^2*d^2)*fv2;
g = r + cw2 (r^6 - r);
r = nut[t, x, y]/(STilda*kappa^2*d^2);
fw = g*((1 + cw3^6)/(g^6 + cw3^6))^(1/6);
ft2 = ct3 Exp[-ct4*chi^2];



saEQN = mu (D[nut[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y]*D[nut[t, x, y], x]) == 
   cb1*(1 - ft2)*STilda*
     nut[t, x, 
      y] - (cw1 fw - (cb1/\[Kappa]^2)*ft2)*(nut[t, x, y]/d)^2 + (1/
        sigma (D[(mu + mut) D[nut[t, x, y], x], x] + 
         D[(mu + mut) D[nut[t, x, y], y], y]) + 
      cb2/sigma*(D[nut[t, x, y], x]^2 + D[nut[t, x, y], y]^2));
mut = rho*nut[t, x, y]*fv1;
fluidEQN = 
  D[u[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y]*D[u[t, x, y], x] + px == 
   D[(1 + mut/mu) D[u[t, x, y], y], y] + D[u[t, x, y], x, x];

eq = {saEQN, fluidEQN}; bcUpdate = {nut[t, x, 0] == 0, 
  u[t, x, 0] == 0, nut[t, x, L] == 0.1, u[t, x, L] == 1, 
  nut[t, 0, y] == 0.1 y/L, u[t, 0, y] == y/L, 
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][nut][t, L, y] == 0, 
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, L, y] == 0}; ic = {nut[0, x, y] == 
   0.1 y/L, u[0, x, y] == y/L}; L = 10^4;
t0 = 15;
px = 0;
Monitor[{nutTGP, uTGP} = 
   NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bcUpdate}, {nut, u}, {t, 0, t0}, {x, 0, 
     L}, {y, 0, L}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = 
       Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];, monitor]
```

Visualization

```
{Plot3D[nutTGP[t0, x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot3D[uTGP[t0, x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: (+1) Thanks for you time Alex. Please allow for a few days to study this.